# string.format from xml wont work

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an XML field that I try to print it with commas in the thousands (example : 1,234)

this is my code :

```
<span><%=String.Format("{0:n}", dc.GetXMLField(nl[i], "PRICE")) + " ₪"%></span>
```

When I run this, I get the number without any commas (for example : 200000)
by the way, its a string..

thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dc.GetXMLField` is returning a string, not a formatable number (int, decimal, etc), but in order for `string.Format("{0:n}", num)` to work, num has to be an `actual` number, not a string representation of a number.

If you know this will always be a number you could parse it into a number first, before attempting to format it:

```
String.Format("{0:n}", int.Parse(dc.GetXMLField(nl[i], "PRICE")))
```

Comment: Indeed ! ... *by the way, its a string..*

Comment: Thanks @Rob Levine, When I try this, it says that "Input string was not in a correct format."  any ideas?

Comment: @thormayer erm... yes, the input is not a number...? Tweak with NumberStyles.Any or check regional options. Also, make sure that the xml field doesn't actually contain random text :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int Number = 0;
if (int.TryParse("200000", out Number))
{
    Response.Write(String.Format("{0:n}", Number, "PRICE"));
}
```

> **Result** - 200,000.00

---

```
(200000).ToString("N", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

> **Result** - $200,000.00

---

```
String.Format("{0:C}", 200000);
```

> **Result** - 200,000.00